# Fabric On Unity: the crash method throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: unity-game-engine, proguard, crashlytics, google-fabric

I Use Unity 2017.1.0p5 compiling for Android with Gradle+Proguard. 
Also Fabric with Crashlytics.
NonFatals seems to be OK and are thrown to the dashboard nicely.
But i've been trying to Crash the app on purpose to test that everything is setup nicely.

So, i ran "Fabric.Crashlytics.Crashlytics.Crash();" on one of my internal builds (on Android), Bummed out the Crash was NOT being reported... instead a NonFatal is given:

```
02-08 11:28:51.779 12983 13013 E Unity   : AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.fabric.unity.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsAndroidWrapper
02-08 11:28:51.779 12983 13013 E Unity   : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.fabric.unity.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsAndroidWrapper
02-08 11:28:51.779 12983 13013 E Unity   :      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-08 11:28:51.779 12983 13013 E Unity   :      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
02-08 11:28:51.779 12983 13013 E Unity   :      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
02-08 11:28:51.779 12983 13013 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
02-08 11:28:51.779 12983 13013 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
02-08 11:28:51.779 12983 13013 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
02-08 11:28:51.779 12983 13013 E Unity   :      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
02-08 11:28:51.779 12983 13013 E Unity   :      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
02-08 11:28:51.779 12983 13013 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)
02-08 11:28:51.779 12983 13013 E Unity   : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.fabric.unity.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsAndroidWrapper" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/user/0/com.theangrykraken.wordbang/app_working/tapjoy.dex", dex file "/data/user/0/com.theangrykraken.wordbang/app_working/vungle.dex", dex file "/data/user/0/com.the
```

I get that from logcat.
That can also be seen on the dashboard, as a NonFatal, and the boat didn't sink, the app kept running.

It might have nothing to do with Proguard, but im using Proguard, configured for Fabric as said here:
https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html

It seems it's missing a class.
Im worried that REAL crashes doesn't get reported properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. If you're causing a Unity runtime exception then those will always show up as a non-fatal, caught exception. If you're causing a fatal crash in Java and that's not showing up as a crash, then that's a different issue. Based on what I see I think you're causing a Unity exception, but perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: No no, I'm calling "Fabric.Crashlytics.Crashlytics.Crash();" in order to test Crashes.. doing that provokes the error above and appears as a NONFATAL on the dashboard

Comment: Gotcha and that has me confused as well. Can you try using Crashlytics.getInstance().crash() on Android?

Comment: Sorry for the delay...  getinstance() does not exists on the Crashlytics class. I'm using Unity with C#

Comment: Tried with 'Crashlytics.SetDebugMode(true);' and 'Fabric.Crashlytics.Crashlytics.Crash()' after, and still got the same error as I said Before

Comment: Gotcha, in that case I'd recommend emailing support(at)fabric(dot)io with the package name of your app so that we can dig in more. Please reference this thread on the email.

Comment: Ok, I have some new.... not good news, but I advanced this topic a bit. I did a new Unity Project with my same Bundle ID. Imported Fabric + Crashlitycs succesfully and I didn't add Gradle+Proguard. The build went great, and after Fabric.Crashlytics.Crashlytics.Crash(); the app crashed sucessfully and was reported on the Dashboard. However, I added Proguard and the Proguard specs and got the same error again.

Comment: I'm Using this: `#Fabric
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**`  as said in here -> https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html

Comment: I'm I missing anything on the ´proguard-user.txt´ ?

Comment: Again, I'd recommend reaching out to support(at)fabric(dot)io at this point so we can dig in more.